# Kivy custom widget instanciated twice

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I'm trying to build a simple Kivy custom widget containing two sliders.
When the screen is rendered I get two pairs of sliders instead of one.

What am I doing wrong ?

**Main.kv:**

```
ScreenManagement:
    MainScreen:

<Button>:
    size_hint: .2, .1
    font_size: 20

<Mixer>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    Slider:
        min:0
        max:127
        value:64
    Slider:
        min:0
        max:127
        value:100

<MainScreen>:
    name: "mainscreen"
    Mixer:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Exit"
            pos: root.width - self.width, 0
            on_release: app.stop()
```

**Main.py:**

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Mixer(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("Main.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I ran your code and I can see two sliders and one button.

Comment: Jeez ! Thanks for your feedback; Then maybe it's due to my configuration / version of Python. I'm running Python 2.7.12 with latest Kivy (1.9.1) on Windows 10. Although I have to mention that the result is the same on my Raspberry Pi (4 sliders instead of two). Weird.

Comment: Try renaming the kv file to ,,main.kv'' and don't load it explicitly in `build` method. It should be loaded automatically.

Comment: @jligeza : Thank you so much, that totally did the trick !! ;)

Comment: Let me rewrite the answer, so it is easier for future readers to search.

Answer (score 3):

You should rename the kv file to `main.kv`, and delete the explicit load of it in `build` method. It is going to load itself automatically. The bug is weird, maybe worth a ticket.

Comment: This is still the case.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of Kivy automatically searches and loads kv filename equal to your class name, excluding App postfix (if exists within class name).
So in your case Kivy will automatically load main.kv, so you don't need to load it explicitly within build method.

Either remove build method in your class:

```
class MainApp(App):
    pass
```

or rename your kv file (for example to main_layout.kv), then put it's filename into load_file method as param:

```
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("main_layout.kv")
```